What does "steal so much as a single glance" mean?
I found this text in the book I was reading namely, "And the mountain echoed":

They said its eyes shone red. No one knew for sure, you understand, at least no one living: The div ate on the spot those who dared steal so much as a single glance. Knowing this, the villagers wisely kept their eyes glued to the ground.

As for the second sentence, I wonder what it means to "steal so much as a single glance". I know that to steal a glance means to look quickly and secretly. But I couldn't understand what "so much as a single glance" means. Did the writer metaphorically combine the conventional meaning of stealing (taking something that belongs to someone else) with the meaning of "stealing a glance"? Additionally, I found this usage of steal in the Cambridge Dictionary that might be related:

To do something quickly or without being noticed:
She stole a glance at her watch.


"I know that to steal a glance means to look quickly and secretly." - that's pretty much exactly what this means. Whoever looked at the div, even if it was just a single brief look, got eaten.

Yes. "so much as...' is used about a tiny amount or number, (the smallest amount possible) of something. When I cleaned the kitchen there was not so much as one tiny speck of dust left.

@MichaelHarvey Thanks for the explanation. I didn't look up the meaning of "so much as".

@Etemon
so much as =
phrase of so,
even

The question doesn't seem to be about the meaning of steal a glance, which the OP already understands. It's the construction so much as a single XXX that confuses the OP. So here's the same construction in a context where the meaning is more obvious...

This liquid is a deadly poison. If you drink so much as a single drop, you will die.


Note that we usually use so much as [some small amount] in adjectival contexts comparing to an actual amount (e.g. - how much there is of it). But it's usually as much as in adverbial contexts (e.g. - how much someone does something)...


...but that's just established idiomatic preference with my example. It would be syntactically and semantically fine with ...as much as a single drop.

+1. Adding to the complexity, I believe "dared steal [...]" and "so much as [...]" are both negative polarity items, like "any" and "ever". In the OP's example they seem to be licensed by "those who", and in your example the "so much as" is licensed by "if".

The phrase so much as is pretty much synonymous with even: “You will die if you drink even a single drop”, “It ate those who dared steal even a single glance.”

@PLL: Well, I'd have no hesitation in classifying even as an "intensifier" in such contexts (the relevant section within the full OED says In weakened use as an intensive or emphatic particle). But so/as much as [small amount] both look like "comparatives" to me, so they're not quite the same, Plus, of course, even can be used to intensify the comparative (even so much as and even as much as are both in common use).

@FumbleFingers I don't think "so much as" is really used as a comparative. In most cases, it just intensifies the smallness of the quantity succeeding it. The sentence usually makes grammatical sense when you omit the phrase (but is less intense), and what's more, it doesn't even need to precede a quantity, e.g. "If you so much as touch a hair on that boy's head...". "As much as", on the other hand, very much can be used a comparative: "I drank as much as she did!", though I have seen it used in lieu of "so much as" as well.

Yes, I quite agree that it's not really a comparative in the context under consideration. But I don't particularly register any sense of tautology in even so/as much as, so one way or another, they feel "different" to me. Anyway, I did point out that we usually use as much rather than so much when it's a true comparative. And nobody says I drank even as/so much as she did.

The phrase those who dared steal so much as a single glance means  everyone who had the nerve (audacity, courage, temerity, foolishness, recklessness, etc.) to look, even momentarily and even once.  In particular, the scrap so much as means even.

"stole a glance" meaning.
OP has given the meaning of the idiom.

Ref. Collins dictionary
If you steal a glance at someone or something, you look at them quickly so that nobody sees you looking.
He stole a glance at the clock behind her. [ + at]

In the story, "And the Mountain Echoed," Div is a monster. The sentence meaning is that if anyone looked at the monster even once would be eaten. So the villagers avoided it by staring at the ground.

Why not use the present when explaining it?
